# Upload Photo to server including location information (Lat/Long)

Tags: ios, geolocation, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, photo-upload

Why is it so hard to upload a photo with Location data in its exif to the server? I am breaking my head not being able to solve this. Whenever I am sending the photo to the server all of its location information is being stripped off from the photo.

I have tried getting UIImage from the UIImagePickerController using both

```
NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

and also UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage.

Kindly someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the exif info, you need to use the raw data, not just the UIImage. You can get it from the ALAsset's defaultRepresentation, something like this:

```
ALAssetRepresentation* representation = [myAsset defaultRepresentation];
int size = representation.size;
NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithCapacity:size];
void* buffer = [data mutableBytes];
[representation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0 length:size error:nil];
data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:buffer length:size];
```

I'm not near xcode to test it right now, but it should work.

Comment: Your my savior... Thank you.. You put me in the right direction. I'll paste the code in here soon for reference..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CLLocation` to get the current location. 
At the time of image upload to server you need to need to get the current location through `CLLocationManager` and update this location parameters to server with the captured image.

Please check the [reference link for location update and how to upload photos](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

Comment: Amit, I dont want to do that.. I have server code which gets location information from the photo. so I need to be able to upload a photo with location information integrated in it.

Comment: Hello shyamsundar, i think there is no script or code through which we can get location from a image.  i have done same in my recently uploaded app.

Comment: Dude. There is ALAssets library which you need to use to get the information... Ill post the code soon. You can take a look in to it. May be you would want to try this in your app instead...